# nVidia driver Failed Install

Tags: 11.10, drivers, nvidia

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How well do laptops with Nvidia Optimus work?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/36930/how-well-do-laptops-with-nvidia-optimus-work)

If I try to install the driver for my nvidia 320M card it shows me

> Sorry, this driver installation failed. For more information, please refer to the log file: / var / log / jockey.log

and the last record in /var/log/jockey.log is

> 2011-10-26 12:36:29,561 ERROR: XorgDriverHandler.enable(): package or module no$
>   2011-10-26 12:36:50,173 DEBUG: NVidia(nvidia_current).enabled(): target_alt /us$
>   2011-10-26 12:36:50,173 DEBUG: KMH enabled: False
>   2011-10-26 12:36:50,214 DEBUG: NVidia(nvidia_current).enabled(): target_alt /us$
>   2011-10-26 12:36:50,214 DEBUG: KMH enabled: False

Comment: Which driver did you try to install? The nvidia binary blob from the official Nvidia site or did you use the Additional Drivers interface? Also which driver version did you try to install

Comment: @Anarci he clearly specifies jokey

Answer (score 0):

Nvidia hybrid solutions are not supported by the current driver. You need to make further adjustments to make your system run with a hybrid solution. The most common and known to work is Bumblebee.

[Bumblebee](https://github.com/Bumblebee-Project/Bumblebee) and your graphics card were already largely discussed [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/36930/how-well-do-laptops-with-nvidia-optimus-work/36936#36936). Have a look.

Basic recommendation is stay away from hybrid, nvidia does not give driver support for linux on those yet!